# Spring service layer write file

Tags: java, spring

I have this method in spring service layer. But it cannot write to file and there is no exception. What's wrong with my code?

```
public void addLineToFile(String file, String line) {
    try {
        ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource(file);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(cpr.getFile());
        outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CustomerToFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CustomerToFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit code giving your purpose and some more code related to it.

Comment: Can you share with us the complete stack trace execption?

Answer (score 0):

Should call the [flush()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush()) of FileOutputStream before close of stream.

Comment: Please add more description to your answer. It will help questioner in grasping more out of your answer.